# Is there something similar to PHP form action on ASP.NET?

Tags: php, asp.net, forms, webforms

I have a aspx page that verify an ID like this:

```
pagename.aspx?id=45678
```

I know in PHP you can do someting like this:

```
<form action="/pagename.php" method="get">
  First name: <input type="id" name="id">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Can you do something similar on ASP.NET?

Comment: That's not PHP by the way, that's just HTML and how HTML forms work.

Comment: "ASP.NET" is really broad. Are you using Web Forms? MVC? Web Pages? Web API? Nancy?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479002.aspx --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409389/converting-asp-net-form-to-html-form --- and I stand to get haggled about this but here's another on *that* site everbody "loves" https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_inputforms.asp - These findings after a simple Google search: *"how to convert a php html form to asp"*.

Comment: Not ure. I am new in this. I am editing some aspx and aspx.cs files.

Comment: If you have ASPX.cs files, then you're using [Web Forms](https://www.asp.net/web-forms). It's kind of important for you to know exactly what it is you're using. You should mention that in your question. Anyways, in Web Forms, you typically have a single form on the page, and it will have the `runat="server"` attribute, and you wouldn't set the action attribute.

Comment: Does it mean that I cannot do what I want to do? How do you suggest? I have this page that do something with the ID on the URL. How can I get that ID from a form?

Answer (score -1):

pagename.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TBid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="Search"  onclick="Button1_Click"  />
```

pagename.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("pagename.aspx?id=" + TBid.Text);
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer. If you need to clarify your question, please edit it (there is a link under the question). Please do not post additional information about the question as an answer. If this *is* supposed to be an answer, please add some information to provide context. Right now, it is not at all clear what you are saying.